# how to convert words to integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to convert a string to integer
the word in range of [zero to ten]

Example Input 1:

```
a=two3four
```

Needed Output:

```
 234
```

Example 2:

```
b=fivesixseven
```

Needed Output:

```
567
```

My code:

```
def w2n (number):
  words = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
  return "".join(str(words.index(number[i])) for i in range(0,len(number)))

print(w2n("onetwoseven"))
```

I am getting error in this code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HelloWorld.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(w2n("onetwoseven"))    
  File "HelloWorld.py", line 3, in w2n
    return "".join(str(words.index(number[i])) for i in range(0,len(number)))
  File "HelloWorld.py", line 3, in <genexpr>
    return "".join(str(words.index(number[i])) for i in range(0,len(number)))
ValueError: 'o' is not in list
```

Please guide me why this error occurs and how to get output for my two example input(given).

Comment: `number[i]` is a single letter.

Comment: @DYZ is right your `words.index` is the single character at index `i`, which is why in the example error message you've given you're seeing `'o' in not in list`, this is the first letter of `"one"` in `"onetwoseven"`.

Comment: I wrongly return my code I don't know how to split onetwothree to ["one","two","three"]

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I came up with :

```py
def w2n(number):
    words = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
    for i in words:
        number = number.replace(i, str(words.index(i)))
    return int(number)


a="two3four"
print(w2n(a)) # 234
b="fivesixseven"
print(w2n(b)) # 567
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to extract digits and their names, then replace the extracted names with their digital representations, and combine those into a string. Bear in mind that "ten" is not a digit and should not be on the list.

```
import re

# A dictionary of names of digits
digits = {'zero': '0', 'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4', 
          'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight': '8', 'nine': '9'}
digits.update({str(i): str(i) for i in range(10)})

# The regular expression for searching the names
numbers = re.compile("|".join(digits))

"".join(digits[w] for w in numbers.findall("two3four"))
#'234'
"".join(digits[w] for w in numbers.findall("fivesixseven"))
#'567'
```

Comment: Hello @DYZ  I have one doubt in this code what is the use of "|" in re.compile?

Comment: "|" in a regular expression means "or".

Answer (score 0):

The regex answer is very clever, but if you want a non-regex solution, you could use the length of the numbers-as-words to get their start & end index in the original input:

```py
def w2n(number):
    words = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]

    for word in words:
        if word in number:
            start = number.index(word)
            end = start + len(word)
            print(f'Word "{word}" starts at {start} and ends at {end}')
            extracted_word = number[start:end]
            number = number.replace(word, str(words.index(extracted_word)) )

    return number

print( w2n('two3four') )

print( w2n('fivesixseven') )
```

By overwriting the original input with each word's numerical representation, we ignore any digits in the input and leave them in place as you can see with the `"two3four"` example.

This would output:

```py
Word "two" starts at 0 and ends at 3
Word "four" starts at 2 and ends at 6
234

Word "five" starts at 0 and ends at 4
Word "six" starts at 1 and ends at 4
Word "seven" starts at 2 and ends at 7
567
```

Comment: @PangoloinPaws  thank you so much sir I understood now